Azure Service Bus Trigger Function Not Achieving Desired Concurrency Levels
I have implemented a system where requests are processed asynchronously using an Azure Service Bus. These requests initiate an operation that, once complete, returns a response to the initiating actor. My objective is to manage the flow of requests to OpenAI efficiently, particularly by limiting the number of concurrent requests to 8 to prevent token bottlenecks.
I have configured my host.json as follows to achieve this limit:
{
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "batchOptions": {
        "maxMessageCount": 1,
        "autoComplete": true
      },
      "prefetchCount": 8,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": true,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 8
      }
    }
  }
}


Additionally, I have set the environment variables
WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT and FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT to 1.
Despite these configurations and referencing Azure Functions, the Service Bus queue often has many messages, but the actual number of concurrent requests remains low (typically 1 or 2).
Why might the Azure Service Bus Trigger Function not be achieving the expected level of concurrency given these settings? What changes should I consider to ensure the number of concurrent requests consistently reaches the limit of 8?


Based on the configuration you have provided, it seems that you have correctly limited the number of concurrent requests to 8 by setting the maxConcurrentCalls option to 8 in the messageHandlerOptions section of your host.json file. Additionally, you have set the prefetchCount option to 8, which means that the Service Bus client will fetch up to 8 messages at a time.
